# writing to a file (?isolated storage wp7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

this code for writing the value of text box to the file but it doesn't create a file even when i used an exist file it's still empty!!

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     string url =infooo.ur + txtb1.Text +  "/" + passtxx.Password + "/1/570322308ce1121cba1b93f5acc9ebd4733ef2bca90ef942a2cfa224f0aa08dc/1";
     client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));

     IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

     IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = iso.CreateFile("T11.txt");

     StreamWriter streamWrite = new StreamWriter(stream);

     streamWrite.Write(txtb1.Text);

     streamWrite.Close();

 }
```

Comment: no in this code no exceptions :(

Comment: If you break on the streamWrite.Write(txtb1.Text); line - is there a value for the textbox?

Comment: ya there's a value on the txtbox but it dosent save it.

Comment: And how do you know that the file isn't saved?

Comment: not saved at the solution or D doesn't created and when i create a file by me and write into it doesn't written into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure your file was NOT saved try this to list your isolated storage:
http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/